# Using built in AEM form

Tags: aem

The form component in AEM and all other form related components mandate that it should be used under parsys component (by dragging and dropping). When I use these form components without a parsys as their parent, are not behaving as expected for ex: form end component does not show submit button even though i have checked the option to show submit button.

Question: I want to use the form components but I don't want to use drag and drop. I want to create a reusable form component with predefined fields. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of searching, I found the best solution here :

http://versatileankur.blogspot.in/2014/11/component-with-default-components-in-cq5.html